# Exception in Ahead() method

Tags: robocode

I have created AdvancedRobot. After first round in Run() I have got exceptions from Ahead method.

```
 public override void Run()
 {
        //...
        var moveAmount = Math.Max(BattleFieldWidth, BattleFieldHeight);
        Ahead(moveAmount);
        //...
 }
```

The exceptions are:

> System.InvalidCastException: „Unable to cast object of type 'net.sf.robocode.dotnet.peer.ExecCommands' to type 'net.sf.robocode.dotnet.peer.ExecResults'.”

and

> java.lang.Throwable; 
>   StackTrace    „($exception).StackTrace”: 
>   „System.InvalidCastException” {System.InvalidCastException}
>   Source    "jni4net.n-0.8.7.0"

As a result my robot has a label "Disabled" and doesn't move. 
Have you got any ideas?

I use Robocode for .NET.

Comment: You need to add the source code for your `Ahead` method to the question

Comment: I use method from Robocode: http://robocode.sourceforge.net/docs/robocode.dotnet/html/42edc934-b4e1-0785-a8cb-5aecbc876d9b.htm

Comment: where in your code do you set moveAmount? are you casting it to a double?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: try `var moveAmount = (double)Math.Max(BattleFieldWidth, BattleFieldHeight);`

Comment: it doesn't help